# passing classpath to custom tasks in java/scala based project within buildr

Tags: java, scala, buildr

I am using buildr to build my scala project and suppose I want to run a main program among the source code, I need to define custom task within buildr which is very easy. However, how can I pass the classpath dependency automatically?(i.e) suppose you have a large number of jar files added already as dependency within buildr. Is there anyway to ask buildr to flatten them out and give it as a classpath so that I can pass it to my scala runner ? I don't want to manually construct the classpath within buildr.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use `buildr`, but it seems to me that a combination of the information on the following pages should get you where you want to go:

- http://buildr.apache.org/more_stuff.html#java
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BUILDR/How+to+create+a+classpath